# Handlebars can't display images

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

So I have images in folder ./public/images, I included in my app the line

```
app.use(express.static('./public/images'));
```

I have several views, but pictures are displayed only in one of them. Why? Even when the code is copypasted. It just works only in one view

Comment: What are the URLs to the images you are putting in your template?  To make `express.static()` work properly and consistently, you have to have the `express.static()` statement and the URLs to your images and the file system all match properly.  We need to see what all three are in order to understand the issue.  And, if your URLs are not absolute URLs (that start with a `/`, then that can cause problems in different views too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this, for src use /images/random.jpg

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
```